# Scraping for a span using Python and BeautifulSoup returns nothing

Tags: python, string, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract an specific text from this link:

http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/mercado/index-20121030.shtml

I wrote this function to find and extract a piece of text:

```
def manchete_11112011_30102012(b):
    soup = make_soup(b)
    data = [span.string for span in soup.find("font")]
    noticias = [b.text for b in soup.findAll("a")]
    return {"noticias": noticias,
            "data": data}
```

OK. My problem is with the **"data"** line. When it runs it return nothing. When I write **"span.string"** it return **"[none]"** and when I write **"span.text"** it return **"[u"]"**

Here is the HTML code I'm looking for. I need the text content inside `<span id="spanLongDate">`:

```
<<td width="430" align="right"><font size="1"><span id="spanLongDate">São Paulo, terça-feira, 30 de outubro de 2012</span></font><img src="images/mercado.gif" hspace="10" alt="Mercado"></td>
```

Is there any other way I could extract the text? I mean, am I writing the code wrong, or is the text format not compatible? And what does "[u"]" mean?

Comment: This tag `td` seems to have double `<` in the beginning of the cited HTML code.

Comment: Ok, so, I guess your problem might be that naming a variable to 'span' will not make it match to span tags in itself.

Comment: Maybe that is the problem, @Berci. I do not know how to be more accurate as this "span" does not have a class. How can I specify this id = "spanLongDate" in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To find the `id = spanLongDate` use the following fragment

```
//get the span you are looking for
span = soup.find("span", attrs = {"id":"spanLongDate"}) 

//get the text out of the span
data = span.get_text()
```

Please note this will only get one instance if you have to find multiple instances use `.find_all`

ETA:

Based on your below comment I went and looked at the page source and even ran it on my machine.  Here is a function that allows you to dump out what beautifulsoup is seeing.  This is helpful because sometimes it doesn't see what you see when you view the source in the browser.

```
def dumpPage():

    url = "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/mercado/index-20121030.shtml"
    print("url is: " + url)
    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    print("read soup")
    print(soup)
```

When I printed it out and searched for "spanLongDate" I got the following fragment of interest.

```
<td align="right" width="430"><font size="1"><span id="spanLongDate"></span></font><img alt="Mercado" hspace="10" src="images/mercado.gif"/></td>
```

This has no Sao Paulo text in it.  I then hit F12 in my Chrome browser to find the raw source and there was also no text in the `spanLongDate` `<div>`.

Perhaps the page was updated?

Comment: You are awsome @dstudeba. Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this `<span id="spanLongDate">São Paulo, terça-feira, 30 de outubro de 2012</span>` has no text neither string objects. I still cannot extract **São Paulo, terça-feira, 30 de outubro de 2012**. Do you know how can I retrieve it? Thanks again.

Comment: I followed your link and looked at the source and indeed that isn't there.  The code works, but there is not text.  I am updating my answer to have more information for you.  I don't know where you got your original html text from but it isn't there currently.

Comment: I do not know what could have happened. I was retrieving dates normally from 2006 to 2011 but since 11/11/2011 the site changed it's script. I do not think this is due to an update. There is no reason for them to remove the newspaper release date. I think their programing that is weak, specially because they have changed the site script in 30/12/2012. Anyway, thanks for the help, you were very kind. Hope you know any other way to extract this date!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the date you should look for it in other places.  If you dump out the soup and then search for 2012 you will see it in a number of places.  It is easy to get it out of the title with the following code.

```
url = "http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/mercado/index-20121030.shtml"
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
theDateTag = soup.find("title")
theDateString = theDateTag.get_text()
print(theDateString)
```